# Change Android AVD SD Card Location?

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I've read other topics here on SO but nothing that fixes that I need. I have a very limited amount of space on my C: drive, which is where the SDK Manager currently wants to install the AVDs to. I need this to be in my F: drive, because that's where my free space is. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mksdcard in the sdk to create an sdcard wherever you'd like then specify this as the sdcard for the avd.

mksdcard 1024M sdcard1.iso

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#sdcard